# Export Html Table to Excel - All Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, export-to-excel

I am having trouble exporting my html table to Excel here is what I have tried.

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#myTableDiv').html()));
```

Works amazingly on chrome, but does not work on Internet explorer;  Just goes to a new tab with the data in the url (tried on IE10). So I tried checking for IE and then using the ActiveXObject method for IE browsers.

```
var objExcel = new ActiveXObject ("Excel.Application");
```

But It gave me errors when creating the object and I have Excel 2013 on my computer. This method does not seem very reliable.

So now I am on to attempting it with a server side language (JSP).

Here is my current attempt.

```
$('.toExcel').click(function(){
    $.post('controllers/excel.jsp?tableHTML=' + encodeURIComponent($('#myTableDiv').html()), function(data) {   

    });
});
```

And my JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="java.io.PrintWriter" %>  
<%@ page contentType="application/excel" language="java" %>  
<%    
   response.reset();  
   response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"report.xls\"");  
   PrintWriter op = response.getWriter();  
   String CSV = request.getParameter("tableHTML");   
   op.write(CSV);  
%>
```

I know there are at least a few issues with this.

1. When posting to the url there is no download prompt.
2. Only so much html can fit as a parameter

When I navigate to the request url in chrome it downloads the file.
When I navigate to the request url in IE 10 I get the following error:

```
  HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. The shortest valid doctype is "<!DOCTYPE html>". 
  excel.jsp, line 1 character 1
```

Can anyone help me with a reliable solution that will work for all browsers?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @VincePettit Well I did find a solution using `jsp` a server side language.  But have not found a strictly `client-side` solution that works.  Are you interested in the `jsp` solution?

Comment: Yes please, if you could let me know your workaround that would be great.

Comment: @VincePettit Okay I'll work on getting the answer up.

Comment: @VincePettit okay posted it.. Let me know if it works for you.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Solution using `JSP` and `JavaScript`

1. Export to Excel JS function. `Pass in table ID`

   ```
   function exportToExcel(intable){
       intable = document.getElementById(intable);
       this.table = intable.cloneNode(true);
       var cform = document.createElement("form");
       cform.style.display = "none";
       cform.setAttribute("method","POST");
       cform.setAttribute("action","exporttoexcel.jsp");
       cform.setAttribute("name","ExcelForm");
       cform.setAttribute("id","ExcelForm");
       cform.setAttribute("enctype","MULTIPART/FORM-DATA");
       cform.encoding="multipart/form-data";
       var ta = document.createElement("textarea");
       ta.name = "ExcelTable";
       var tabletext = this.table.outerHTML;
       ta.defaultValue = tabletext;
       ta.value = tabletext;
       cform.appendChild(ta);
       intable.parentNode.appendChild(cform);
       cform.submit();
       //clean up
       ta.defaultValue = null;
       ta = null;
       tabletext = null;
       this.table = null;
   }
   ```
2. And the `code` for `exporttoexcel.jsp`

   ```
   <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
   <%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
   <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
   <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
   <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
   <%
   response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + "MyReport.xls" );
   boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
   Iterator pit = null;
   DiskFileItem dfi = null;
   String line = ""; 
   if(isMultipart){
       //      Create a factory for disk-based file items
       FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

       //      Create a new file upload handler
       ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

       //      Parse the request
       File f = null;
       dfi = null;
       List items = null;
       items = upload.parseRequest(request);
       pit = items.iterator();

    }
    if(isMultipart){
       while(pit.hasNext()){
           dfi = (DiskFileItem)pit.next();
           String name = dfi.getFieldName();
           if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("ExcelTable")){
               InputStream is = dfi.getInputStream();
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
               while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                   out.println(line);
               }                                   
           }
        }
     }else{
       Enumeration params = request.getParameterNames();
       while(params.hasMoreElements()){
           String par = (String)params.nextElement();
           out.println(par+"<br>");
           out.println(request.getParameter(par));
       }
     }
   %>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I will tell you a simple solution

add one button in the page  where table is

```
<button class="btn btn-success">Export Data to Excel</button>
```

now add the below given scripts to the same page

```
<script src="js/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
 <script>
      $(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
           $("#tableID").table2excel({
             exclude: ".noExl",
             name: "Excel Document Name"
           });
        });
     });
</script>
```

Do not forget to download  jquery.table2excel.js and add this to js folder

Comment: can you add a link or the javascript for the jquery.table2excel.js file?  Also do you know if this works on IE 9 and above?

Comment: Yes instead of button we can have a link by using <a></a> tag.Give that an id or class name and in script function instead of button call that link with id or class name

Comment: Sorry I meant a link to the "download jquery.table2excel.js" that you mention.

Comment: do you want link for the .js file??

Comment: @Aditya Thanks for this technique, but i get these errors while trying this approach, `SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number` and `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'table2excel' `. Could you please share the link to download the proper jquery.table2excel.js. It might be helpful for many.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @Disera https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/blob/master/src/jquery.table2excel.js

you can download the js file from the above link and put that file into folder named js